# Using openshift along with unix pipes

Tags: openshift, openshift-3

I was wondering if it would be possible to pipe some json/yaml into an oc comand similar to this:

`cat some.yaml|oc update`

Comment: Usually, you would `oc apply -f -` where the `-` at the end reads from stdin/piped data

Answer (score 0):

These commands are actually pretty much frequently used in Openshift.

```
cat some.yaml | oc apply -f-
cat some.yaml | oc replace -f-
```